# Navigation Case extension

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere-7, icefaces-3

I am trying to navigate to an xhtml page in a static web project. My original context is a dynamic web project with icefaces 3.3. It redirects to the below path with `.faces` even when I specify .xhtml as outcome in the `to-view-id`. Is there any way to make it redirect to `.xhtml` instead?

```
http://localhost:9080/staticWebRoot/logout.faces
```

**faces-navigation.xml**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/../../staticWebRoot/logout.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>     
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should not use navigation rules for non-JSF resources. JSF assumes that all to-view-ids are real JSF views in the current webapp (otherwise, they wouldn't be called "view IDs" in first place).

Just use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void redirect() throws IOException {
    // ... 
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/staticWebRoot/logout.xhtml");
}
```

Comment: This answer works but why does the navigation rule in the question work fine when I use JSF 1.2 and Icefaces 1.8? I just wanted to know if some change was introduced in JSF 2.1